# stackoverflow js is down

Tags: bug, status-norepro

stackoverflow js is down due to some CORS error

[image]

Comment: So you don't see an advertisement, congratulations.  I suspect the people that sell them often get this wrong :)  Worth checking that your browser isn't infected btw, there is a lot of hiding going on.

Comment: that was rude. thanks must have been pushed by my isp using https now.

Comment: Are you sure Stack Overflow uses `http://203.94.243.63:3000` to serve ads ? I kind of doubt it - I think SO would at least use a proper domain to serve ads, not a bare IP adress. As Hans said, you might want to check if your browser is infected or some middleware is injecting ads. Ps: If you were referring to Hans's comment as "rude" - I don't think it is or was intended to be.

Comment: You're not the only one, [blame your ISP](https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/issues/5999).

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266211/stack-overflow-links-not-working

Answer (score 7):

This is an Indian ISP (Mahanagar Telephone Nigam Ltd) MITMing its clients (or being a victim of an attack).

Solutions:

1. Switch ISPs.
2. Kick the ISP in the proverbials, or let an elephant of an acceptable size dance on the same.
3. Switch to HTTPS.
4. Nag Stack Exchange to implement TLS everywhere including on site metas.

Comment: any leads on how to do this - "Kick the ISP in the proverbials, or let an elephant of an acceptable size dance on the same." ;)

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya - this is left as an exercise for the reader (phone the provider's security support team, liberate animals from the zoo, etc.).

Comment: FYI: [Official HTTPS is coming soon](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27677583#27677583). (cc @PradyutBhattacharya).

Comment: @JonasCz - in 6-8 weeks...